# How do I align list content to the left?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to align my list content to the left, but can't quite figure out how. Thanks in advance for any suggestions. Here's a sample of the code:

```html
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
        <i class="fas fa-hiking fa-4x"></i>
        <h4 class="my-4" font-weight-bold>What to bring</h4>
        <p>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                <li>Coffee</li>
                <li>Tea</li>
                <li>Milk</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `padding-left: 0;` for `ul`

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
  <i class="fas fa-hiking fa-4x"></i>
  <h4 class="my-4" font-weight-bold>What to bring</h4>
  <p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding: 0;` to your `<ul>` tag.
It will look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
  <i class="fas fa-hiking fa-4x"></i>
  <h4 class="my-4" font-weight-bold>What to bring</h4>
  <p>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```